# how to condense this code into one single line?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given this array: `arry = [[111,2],[3,4],9]`
I am trying to get this code segment condensed into a single line:

```
for index,item in enumerate(arry):
    if isinstance(item,list or np):
        for index2,item2 in enumerate(item):
            item[index2] = item2 *2
    else:
        arry[index]= item * 2
print(arry)
```

I tried this:
`print([[x*2 for x in y if isinstance(y,list)] for y in arry])`

It works but its missing the else statement. Where should I insert the else statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
print([[x*2 for x in y] if isinstance(y, list) else y * 2 for y in arry])
```

Output:

```
[[222, 4], [6, 8], 18]
```

Comment: thanks this is correct, will mark it right